# How to avoid running drop table query before create table in big query?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am working on an automated big query data ingestion pipeline in python. I am using python API to create SQL string and execute them to create big query tables and append new data to old tables.

I have a section in code where it creates a new table from the old table. After that it drops the old table. But sometimes I am running in an issue where the drop table query gets executed before create table query. To overcome this I am manually setting **time.sleep()** in my script.

Is there a way I can stop the drop table query to get executed before create table query? Below are the snippets of the code I am using.

```
Fnl_DtaNme_Bth = Final_DataName + datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')

    fnl_sql_vw = """
        Create table {} as
            (
            select * from `{}` where row_key not in (select row_key from `{}`)
            union all
            select {} from `{}` 
            )
    """.format(dataset_id + '.' + Fnl_DtaNme_Bth, ProjectID + '.' + dataset_id + '.' + Final_DataName, ProjectID + '.' + dataset_id + '.' + viewname, List_COls, ProjectID + '.' + dataset_id + '.' + viewname)

    print('CreateTable:-->', fnl_sql_vw)

    client = bigquery.Client()
    query_job = client.query(fnl_sql_vw)

    time.sleep(10)

#########       Here we are DROPING Old Mater Data      ##############      
    drop_table = """Drop Table `{}`""".format(ProjectID + '.' + dataset_id + '.' + Final_DataName)

    client = bigquery.Client()
    query_job = client.query(drop_table)
    time.sleep(10)

#########Here we are RE-CREATING Mater Data without BATCH_ID#############       
    fnl_data = """Create table {} as Select * from `{}`""".format( dataset_id + '.' + Final_DataName, ProjectID + '.' + dataset_id + '.' + Fnl_DtaNme_Bth) #args.dataset_id + '.' + Destination_Table
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query_job = client.query(fnl_data)
    time.sleep(10)

 #########Here we are DROPING Mater Data with BATCH_ID ############ #           
    drop_table_old = """
        Drop Table `{}`
    """.format(ProjectID + '.' + dataset_id + '.' + Fnl_DtaNme_Bth)

    client = bigquery.Client()
    query_job = client.query(drop_table_old)
```

As you can see in the code, what I am doing is:

> -create table with batch id
>   -drop old table.(this gets executed first stopping any further steps.)
>   -recreate new table without batch id
>   -drop table from step 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to sleep for the correct amount of time is a bad idea since you don't know how long any particular operation will take. Remove the calls to sleep, and instead wait for results after initiating each query:

```
query_job = client.query(fnl_sql_vw)
# Wait for completion
query_job.result()

drop_table = """Drop Table `{}`""".format(ProjectID + '.' + dataset_id + '.' + Final_DataName)
query_job = client.query(drop_table)
# Wait for completion
query_job.result()

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do an atomic replace of the table?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `deleting.mytable`
AS
# SELECT 1 x
SELECT x+x x 
FROM `deleting.mytable`
```

Comment: I have just started working with the GCP, The script is old, I will surely look for ways to optimize and will keep this tip in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I learned that CREATE OR REPLACE will work if you are changing/adding PARTITION or CLUSTER by clause. Instead you have to use something like this

```
drop table if exists dataset.some_table;
create table if not exists dataset.some_table (
...
)
partition by ...
cluster by ..;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29920131)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).